# Drag mouse to place image over PDF on GUI

Tags: python

I'm an entry of python and i want to know is it possible to make GUI that have function to open PDF file then place and sizing an image over on its at position where i drag a mouse.

I'm try to create a program that use to stamp the Signature on PDF file.

i have tried on `PyMuPDF`, `PysimpleGUI` and `tkinter` but i'm entry level i don't know so much a code.

```
def getpositionxy(event):
    clickx, clicky = event.x, event.y
    print('{}, {}'.format(clickx, clicky))

root.bind('<Double-Button-1>', getpositionxy)

img_rect = fitz.Rect((%i,%i, %i, %i) %(clickx,clicky,clickx + 200, clicky + 200))
imagesig = open("image.PNG", "rb").read()
page.insertImage(img_rect, stream= imagesig)
```

bind function it worked only on `tkinter` window.it not provide a position when i click on `PysimpleGUI`

Comment: Is your posted code correct? You're missing a `:` at the end of your `if` statement, plus all the following code isn't indented.

Comment: PyMuPDF is a good package as it does use PySimpleGUI in some examples and the authors are well versed in PySimpleGUI.  I think what you're trying to do, as a complete beginner, is difficult.  Placing an image, then grabbing to resize it, all the while it's on top of an image of a PDF page isn't what I would call a beginner thing, no matter how much you want it to happen.  There are a number of demo programs in the PySimpleGUI github that may help.